# Label with cross icon in Bootstrap CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using below code to create label

```
<span class="label label-tags">Country 
    <a onclick="javascript:alert(0);" href="javascript:void(0);"> 
     <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
    </a>
</span>
```

CSS Classes:

```
.label-tags {
    background-color: #CBF6FF;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.label {
    border-radius: 0.25em;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 75%;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1;
    padding: 0.2em 0.6em 0.3em;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.fa {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.fa-trash-o:before {
    content: "\f014";
}
```

The above CSS generates label with trash icon but I need cross icon. Please suggest CSS changes to accomplish this.

Comment: Either change the `content` value or the class of `i`.

Comment: If by "cross", you mean "x", then `fa-times`: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/times/.

Comment: @JoshC What should be the content value? Can you explain little bit more?

Comment: @TiesonT. Yes I mean "x", What would be the property for fa-times ?

Comment: Edited comment above, but: `\f00d`

Comment: Thanks! @TiesonT. Surprised why negative voting for this question...hahahaha well win some lose some....

Comment: I believe it may be because you ask why the 'trash' icon is showing, yet directly in your code you do: `<i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>`. If you didn't get that, that's a fundamental misunderstanding of CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

font awesome version - 4.0.3,  fa-times value is `(&#xf00d;)` or `/f00d`

keep it for future reference http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/

Comment: Version 4, actually -> version 3 uses the `icon-` prefix.

Comment: oh it was typo, Thanx alot Tieson :)